# How to select everything from two columns that have matching rows on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

My mobile teams rely on a spreadsheet for localization. With time I realized that each team are using their own keys rather than using the same one. I need to start from scratch and have both teams use the same key. How can I copy over all the rows that have matching keys into another sheet as depicted here?

[image]

so for example in the new sheet I would like to see something like this

```
identifier       | english             | arabic               | 
-----------------+---------------------+----------------------+
credit_card      |credit card          | بطاقة الائتمان        |
cash_on_delivery |cash on delivery     | الدفع نقدا عن الاستلام |
..
```

so notice the row where `identifier iOS` has `cash` will be ignored because the corresponding key in android `label_cash` doesn't match it

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask], specify if you are looking for a formula or script and add a link to a demo spreadsheet (you might find helpful this [
How to share a Google Sheets demo spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/138382/88163))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data sheet is in `Sheet1` you can use the `FILTER` function in your other sheet.

```
=FILTER({Sheet1!A2:B,Sheet1!D2:D},Sheet1!A2:A=Sheet1!B2:B)
```

Have a look how the [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) function works

Comment: Please check the updated answer _(following my initial hasty reply)_

Comment: Have you ever tried this answer?